# Mysql function TO_DAYS incorrect parameters

Tags: mysql, parameters

First of all, I'm no mySQL guru at all so please forgive me if my question is too stupid.

I am trying to get the days difference between 2 dates, but the first one needs to be grabbed using a subquery. Here it is

```
AND TO_DAYS((SELECT DATE(date_add) FROM ps_order_history oh2 WHERE oh2.id_order_state = 4       
AND id_order = o.id_order limit 1) as shdate) < (TO_DAYS(NOW()) - 12)
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong here, since I get the following error:

```
Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'TO_DAYS'
```

Anyone can help perhaps? I really need to use those conditions when getting the other values

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the "`as shdate`", which should be removed.

```
   AND TO_DAYS( (SELECT DATE(date_add) 
                   FROM ps_order_history oh2
                  WHERE oh2.id_order_state = 4
                    AND id_order = o.id_order
                  LIMIT 1
                ) as shdate
-- not valid here ^^^^^^^^^
              ) < (TO_DAYS(NOW()) - 12)
```

If you do want to include an alias, it should be after the expression in the SELECT list, before the FROM keyword. It's not required, but is acceptable like this:

```
   AND TO_DAYS( (SELECT DATE(date_add) AS shdate  
-- alias is valid here                 ^^^^^^^^^
                   FROM ps_order_history oh2
                  WHERE oh2.id_order_state = 4
                    AND id_order = o.id_order
                  LIMIT 1
                ) 
              ) < (TO_DAYS(NOW()) - 12)
```

Comment: I'm so dumb! I tried that but without the outer parenthesys, and it broke. It works now, many thanks!